# how handle aws elastic bean stack 502 bad gateway nginx error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I uploaded my jar to elastic beanstack it started I pressed its given url ,then it gives me 502 nginx error

I tried to add SERVER_PORT in configuration ,didn't help ,then attached policy to its created role :  aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role this policy AmazonSSMReadOnlyAccess
,but again didn't help

Comment: On what port does your jar expect connections? Is 8080?

Comment: 8081.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/7661119/ervin-szilagyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that your jar expects connections on port `8081`, in the other hand Elastic Beanstalk expects that your app has port `5000` opened.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html):

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk configures the nginx proxy to forward requests to your application on port 5000. You can override the default port by setting the PORT environment property to the port on which your main application listens.

You can set an environment variable in the configurations:

[image]

Comment: the same error nothing changed

Comment: Have you set the port to 8081?

Comment: SERVER_PORT = 5000 worked